# Is there a way to detect if a scoped slot was passed in to a component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component that is nested inside several layers of components. A scoped slot can be passed down to this component. I want to detect when it is not.

**Example:**

```
Vue.component("parent", {
    template: `
        <child>
            <template slot="expand" slot-scope="{data}" v-if="$scopedSlots.expand">
                <slot name="expand" :data="data"></slot>
            </template>
        </child>
`,
});

Vue.component("child", {
    template: `
        <div>
            <slot name="expand" :data="1"></slot>
            <div @click="$scopedSlots.expand && log()">Child</div>
        </div>
`,
    methods: {
        log() {
            console.log(this.$scopedSlots.expand);
            console.log("This shouldn't work");
        }
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    template: `<parent></parent>`,
})
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/BehindTheMath/pen/gdBeqY)

In this example, the scoped slot is never passed in from the root component to `<parent>`. As a result, I would have thought that `$scopedSlots.expand` and the `v-if` in `<parent>` would both be falsy, so no slot would be passed to `<child>`, and clicking wouldn't do anything.

However, this appears to be wrong for 2 reasons:

- Since `$scopedSlots.expand` is stored internally as a function, it will always evaluate as truthy, as you can see in the console of the CodePen.
- It appears that `<template>`s always render, even with `v-if="false"`. So even if `$scopedSlots.expand` would evaluate as falsy inside `<parent>`, an empty slot would still be passed down to `<child>`, and `$scopedSlots.expand` inside `<child>` would  evaluate as truthy regardless.

Is there a way to make this work?

I know I can accomplish this by just passing a boolean prop that says whether to process the click. I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to determine from the slot itself.

Comment: the slot template will be compiled to `render function`, even uses `v-if`, it is just one line of logic codes inside that `render function`. If only exists `<slot name="expand" :data="data"></slot>` as the child of `<template slot="expand">`, you can use `this.$parent.$slots.expand`

Comment: @Sphinx true. But that wouldn't work if there were several levels of nesting.

Comment: if so, you may want to use [default slot content & ref](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RYeYqR); Inside this codepen, exists **scoped slot** if `this.$refs.test` is false, otherwise, `this.$refs.test` is true.

Comment: That's an interesting workaround.

Comment: Actually, it won't work in my actual use case, since the slot is for part of the component that gets expanded when the rest of the component is clicked. So the content isn't rendered until after the click handler finishes, and `$refs.test` will be `undefined` regardless.

Answer (score 5):

I've been hit with this before, it's pretty annoying.

The Vue template compiler will compile this

```
<template v-if="false"/>
```

into essentially

```
vm._e()
```

where `_e` is an [internal helper method](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/52719ccab8fccffbdf497b96d3731dc86f04c1ce/src/core/instance/render-helpers/index.js) which is `createEmptyVNode`. So off the bat we know to expect *empty vnodes* instead of falsey values.

If we investigate further by looking at the compiled code for this template

```
<child>
  <template slot="expand" slot-scope="scope" v-if="false"/>
</child>
```

we get this code (which I've simplified a bit to show only the relevant stuff)

```
_c('child', {
  scopedSlots: {
    expand(scope) {
      return undefined
    }
  }
})
```

To summarize: `v-if="false"` does *not* imply that the scoped slot function will be omitted, instead it will be provided but when called it will return `undefined`. So in the child component, you can expect `$scopedSlots.expand` to exist but when called will return `undefined`.

AFAIK there's no easy way to deal with this. A quick "fix" for your example would be

```
<div @click="$scopedSlots.expand() && log()">Child</div>
                                ^^
```

but be wary of

- will your parent component be able to deal with `slot-scope="{data}"` for a nonexistent `{data}`? It might be best to call `$scopedSlots.expand(scope)` with real `scope` data.
- calling `$scopedSlots.expand()` and discarding the potentially truthy result multiple times in a render cycle could be a performance issue.

FWIW I've had *varied* success with separating the `v-if` and `slot` into separate `<template>` nodes:

```
<template v-if="$scopedSlots.expand">
  <template slot="expand" slot-scope="{data}">
    <slot name="expand" :data="data"/>
  </template>
</template>
```

Comment: I can confirm that wrapping another outer `template` for the v-if as @DecadeMoon suggests at the end works for me. I also threw in a `$nextTick` before testing `$scopedSlots` in the child, as this seemed to be necessary in my case. Are there cases where this doesn't work?